# WSO2 API Manager - How to build Http response in custom mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I developed a custom mediator to validate input parameter, and tested it successfully.
but I want to return Http response with some meaningful message to client, like HTTP 403, warning message and etc, any one can tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code just before sending the response.

```
<header name="To" action="remove"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="403" scope="axis2"/>
```

Here it has put 403 to http status code.
Finally you should add `<send/>` mediator.

Thanks.